# It takes an unusually long time to get into command line prompt

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome-terminal, prompt

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and the system is fully updated. Recently I noticed that it takes several seconds to show the prompt when I open the terminal for the first time after login to Ubuntu. That time is unusual. Can you tell me what might be the reason for this?

**

**As this question is on hold now I will explain step by step for those who voted as unclear.**

**

1. Power on the Ubuntu computer.
2. Click on the terminal icon. (terminal opens quicker)
3. Wait for the the PROMT. but it takes at least 10 seconds to show up.
4. Assume, that prompt showed up and I closed the terminal.

**Do it again without rebooting**

5. Reopen the terminal. (opens quicker)
6. Prompt shows up quicker.

If anything unclear please ask me.

Comment: Do you have any custom tweaks in `.bashrc` or similar file? Do they try to find something in the filesystem? Communicate via network?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Actually I don't remember what I did earlier. I did not do anything recently when I see this unusual delay. Can you tell me how to find?

Comment: What happens when using the virtual terminal? Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F1, logging in from there, and doing stuff with the terminal. Does it behave slowly there, or is it fast without a GUI? (You can press Ctrl+Alt+F7 to get back to the GUI desktop environment.)

Comment: @rlee827 yes it is fast without GUI and remember that the problem occurs when I open the terminal for the first time after login to Ubuntu.

Comment: You can try adding `set -x` to the beginning of your `.bashrc`. This will cause bash to print out every single command before executing it. You can watch the output from `set -x` and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: Instead of bumping your post with useless edits, follow the suggestion above^ and add the output here.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're saying the terminal shows up immediately, but the prompt appears after a delay, yes?

Comment: @wjandrea Yes, you are correct

Comment: @rlee827 I do not understand how to do that. I am new here. can you explain please..

Comment: I think voters understand what behaviour you are seeing but there is not enough information to answer. rlee827 and muru suggested how you could get some useful information: open the file `~/.bashrc`, for example type `nano ~/.bashrc`, and at the top of the file add `set -x`. Save and exit, reboot, open a terminal, and copy the output into your question.

Comment: @Zanna thank you for explaining what I should do. I will try it today. i am on the way now. Thanks

Comment: :) that will be great. I'll check back later and vote to reopen

Comment: @Zanna here it is.. https://gist.github.com/nuwanlk/df54b936cdc050456413f56a9c5aa807

Comment: awesome, thank you. Sorry I didn't mention earlier, but could you also post the contents of your .bashrc? (you can remove `set -x` now). (A fast way would be to type `cat ~/.bashrc | pastebinit` - should give you the link)

Comment: I suspect the problem (looking at your output) could be multiple `find` operations being run inside a `for` loop - that sounds verrrrrry slow. Not sure why it would be slower the first time you start bash though

Comment: @Zanna why this? I cannot get in there now... http://telegra.ph/bash-07-01

Comment: looks like an extra dot in the address?

Comment: @Zanna how to fix that?

Comment: I mean it looks like a typo